# kafka zookeeper: no rout to host exception on connect. Strange address format?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Here is the scenario:

1. My kafka server and the zookeeper are running and working fine on the remote server as long as I launch the process on the same remote server.
2. I don't have any connectivity issues between my local machine and the server. I can ssh and access all other applications on my remote server from my local machine.
3. When trying to connect a client to the remote zookeeper directly from my local machine I get a connection timeout. Debugging shows that a NoRouteToHost exception is being thrown.
4. The client logfile contains the following lines:

`org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection,    connectString=remotehost:2181 sessionTimeout=120000
watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@62807a4d

    org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server

remotehost/192.13.12.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using
SASL (unknown error)`

Note the "remotehost/192.13.12.1:2181". The URL I'm specifying is remotehost:2181. He appears to resolve the hostname to IP correctly and then... slapping a forward slash and the IP on to the URL which looks weird to me. Is this how he should resolve and pass down the URL to the socket?? Or is this the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The zookeeper listen port was not open to the firewall.